# How to specify spring.mandatory-file-encoding as UTF-8 in application.yml file?

Tags: character-encoding

I want to add JVM option -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in my application.yml file
I tried using spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8 . But I'm getting the following error :

Type=ERROR,Category=org.springframework.boot.context.**FileEncodingApplicationListener**,Thread=main,MDC=,Text=**System property 'file.encoding' is currently 'Cp1252'. It should be 'UTF-8' (as defined in 'spring.mandatoryFileEncoding')**

Type=ERROR,Category=org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener,Thread=main,MDC=,Text=Environment variable LANG is 'en_US.UTF-8'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'

Type=ERROR,Category=org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener,Thread=main,MDC=,Text=Environment variable LC_ALL is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'

**FileEncodingApplicationListener** :
It halts application startup if the system file encoding does not match an expected value set in the environment. By default has no effect, but if you set {@code spring.mandatory_file_encoding} to the name of a character encoding (e.g. "UTF-8") then this initializer throws an exception when the System property does not equal it.

Click here to read more:

Comment: You can set it when you start your application, for example `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar myapp.jar`

Answer (score -2):

Deleting this property "spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8" from application.properties file helped me.

But first I've changed settings in IntelijIDEA: File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings form "System default" to UTF-8. May be it affected somehow.

Comment: But my question is, how can we set 'spring.mandatory-file-encoding'  though ?

Comment: @AlishaRaju in application.properties